# getting a return value upon ajax save of new form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am using ajax to add form data to the database. My add code works great, but I need somehow to grab the newly created ID and use it in my jquery after the save has succeeded.

Here is my save jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#saveChanges").on("click", function(e) {
        var formData = $("form").serialize();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "newListing/",
            data: formData,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (resp) {
                debugger;
                alert($('#id').val());
                $('#listChosen').html("");
                $('#listChosen').load("/Listing/SearchListing/" + $('#id').val());
                alert("listing added");
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

What I am trying to do is expose the newly created ID from newListing and use it when calling the /SearchListing/.

The controller action I call with new listing is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult newListing(Listing newList)
    {

        _listingservice.NewListing(newList);
        return View();
    }
```

This action filters through my service layer via interfaces to my repository and eventually makes this call:

```
      try
        {
            _entities.Listings.Add(newList);
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }
        return true;
```

upon the savechange() the new ID is available but i dont know how to filter it back down to my success code in the jquery.

Can anyone offer any advice on how I might do this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the newly saved entity from `NewListing`. You don't seem to be using the `View()` that you're currently rendering, so you could just respond with the Id instead:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult newListing(Listing newList)
{
    var entity = _listingservice.NewListing(newList);
    return Content(entity.Id.ToString());
}
```

Then your ajax would receive the id:

```
...
success: function (id) {
   debugger;
   alert(id);
   $('#listChosen').html("");
   $('#listChosen').load("/Listing/SearchListing/" + id);
   alert("listing added");
},
...
```